# How can I show a LineLayer based on coordinates returned from an Azure Maps Traffic Flow Segment?

Tags: azure-maps

There is a good example for [retrieving and showing traffic information](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMapsCodeSamples/blob/main/Samples/Animations/Animated%20traffic%20flow/Animated%20traffic%20flow.html) using the /traffic/flow/tiles method, but not one for /traffic/flow/segment. The /traffic/flow/tiles example suggests using a VectorTileSource datasource, but it's not clear what the equivalent would be for a segment data (perhaps the [DataSource object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/atlas.source.datasource?view=azure-maps-typescript-latest)?)?

Does anyone know what would be the equivalent call to add a datasource based on the coordinates returned as part of the FlowSegmentData. For example, the way shown for traffic/flow/tiles is as follows:

```
       datasource = new atlas.source.VectorTileSource(null, {
       tiles: ['https://{azMapsDomain}/traffic/flow/tile/pbf?api-version=1.0&style=relative&zoom={z}&x={x}&y={y}'],
                maxZoom: 22
       });
       map.sources.add(datasource);enter code here
```

What I'm ultimately trying to do is show LineLayer/animation based on results for a specified traffic flow segments.

Answer (score 1):

The [Traffic Flow Segment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/traffic/get-traffic-flow-segment?tabs=HTTP) isn't a tile service, but a query service. You pass in a coordinate, and it returns a nearby road segment with traffic information. To use this you would first need to decide what coordinate you want to use to retrieve the traffic flow segment. Some ideas:

- User clicks the map and you use that coordinate.
- User does a search for an address, and you use that coordinate.
- Use the center of the map (either after the map has moved or when user presses a button. Note that calling this after the map moves could result in a lot of transactions being created leading to high cost).

Assuming you are targeting a web app, you can use the fetch API to call this service. You can then take the response and create a LineString from the coordinates, then use that with a DataSource and LineLayer like any other simple LineString. Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

    <!-- Add references to the Azure Maps Map control JavaScript and CSS files. -->
    <link href="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var map, datasource;
        
        var coordinate = [-122.10565, 47.67498];
        
        var flowSegmentStyle = 'relative'; //options: absolute, relative, relative-delay
        
        var trafficFlowSegmentUrl = `https://{azMapsDomain}/traffic/flow/segment/json?api-version=1.0&style=${flowSegmentStyle}&zoom={zoom}&query={query}`;

        function GetMap() {
            //Initialize a map instance.
            map = new atlas.Map('myMap', {
                center: coordinate,
                zoom: 14,
                view: 'Auto',

                authOptions: {
                    authType: 'subscriptionKey',
                    subscriptionKey: '[YOUR_AZURE_MAPS_KEY]'
                }
            });

            //Wait until the map resources are ready.
            map.events.add('ready', function () {

                //Create a data source and add it to the map.
                datasource = new atlas.source.DataSource();
                map.sources.add(datasource);

                //Create a line layer and add logic to determine how to style it.
                map.layers.add(new atlas.layer.LineLayer(datasource, null, {
                    strokeWidth: 6,
                    
                    //Color the segment based on the current speed (you can pick some other logic or a use a solid color)
                    strokeColor: [
                        'interpolate',
                        ['linear'],
                        ['get', 'currentSpeed'],
                        0, "green",
                        35, "yellow",
                        70, "red"
                    ]
                }));
                
                //Retrieve a traffic flow segment.
                var url = trafficFlowSegmentUrl.replace('{zoom}', Math.ceil(map.getCamera().zoom)).replace('{query}', `${coordinate[1]},${coordinate[0]}`);
                
                processRequest(url).then(r => {
                    //Turn the cooridnate information into an array of positions.
                    
                    var positions = [];
                    r.flowSegmentData.coordinates.coordinate.forEach(c => {
                        positions.push([c.longitude, c.latitude]);
                    });
                    
                    //Create a LineString feature with the positions and retain the segment data as properies. Add the feature to the data source.
                    datasource.add(new atlas.data.Feature(new atlas.data.LineString(positions), r.flowSegmentData));
                });
            });
        }
        
        //This is a helper function that sets the domain of the request to the same one used by the map (Azure Maps is available in different Azure clouds with different domains e.g. Azure gov cloud). 
        //This also uses the same authenication as the map, making it easy, regardless of the type of auth you use (key or Azure AD).
        function processRequest(url) {
            //This is a reusable function that sets the Azure Maps platform domain, sings the request, and makes use of any transformRequest set on the map.
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                //Replace the domain placeholder to ensure the same Azure Maps cloud is used throughout the app.
                url = url.replace('{azMapsDomain}', atlas.getDomain());

                //Get the authentication details from the map for use in the request.
                var requestParams = map.authentication.signRequest({ url: url });

                //Transform the request.
                var transform = map.getServiceOptions().tranformRequest;
                if (transform) {
                    requestParams = transform(url);
                }

                fetch(requestParams.url, {
                    method: 'GET',
                    mode: 'cors',
                    headers: new Headers(requestParams.headers)
                })
                    .then(r => r.json(), e => reject(e))
                    .then(r => {
                        resolve(r);
                    }, e => reject(e));
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="GetMap()">
    <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:600px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```